# Wait for page to load after click() on download button

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

It is possible to somehow skip waiting for page to load, after Cypress test click() on download button which start download but does not redirect to other page?

```
it('name of the test', () =>{
        cy.get('#btnGeneratePdf').click()
        .url().should('contain', "/Closed"); //url is same as before than button for download was clicked

})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known Cypress problem. A lot of related issues have been opened on [Cypress github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues), however you can follow the main discussion in [this one](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14857).

Right now you cannot skip the Cypress `waiting for load` after clicking the anchor, but there is a workaround - you can force your page to reload after the file has been downloaded, to make the test not fail. There is a 5 seconds timeout that you can adjust to make sure the file gets to download before the page reloads.

```
cy.window().document().then(function (doc) {
  doc.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // this adds a listener that reloads your page 
    // after 5 seconds from clicking the download button
    setTimeout(function () { doc.location.reload() }, 5000)
  })
  cy.get('#btnGeneratePdf').click()
})
```

This issue has been around for a long time. Hopefully Cypress team will resolve it soon.

Comment: How to check from this point that the file has really been downloaded..Also if it contains a zip file how to check what file are present inside the zip file?
Anything done after the cy.get('#btnGeneratePdf').click() is causing a page load issue